# Python - list gets updated outside function without using "return"

Tags: python, list, variables, scope, namespaces

I have a list which I give to a function as argument.
Inside function, I'm altering the list, but I don't return the list using `return`.
I'm running the function and print the list afterwards.

Excpeted result: `[]`

Actual result: `[5]`

How is this possible?

```
def foo(bar):
    for i in range(2):
        if bar == []:
            bar.append(4)
        else:
            bar[0] += 1
            
myvar = []  
foo(myvar)
print (myvar)
```

Comment: There is nothing strange about this. `bar` gets passed the list that is defined in the global scope. Of course mutating that list changes it

Comment: Because, as you say, you are altering the list inside the function.

Comment: Read the following: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: Pretty strange question, tbh. *"I'm modifying list, why does it get modified?"*

Answer (score 1):

Because empty list created first in the memory location and second time it refers same list instead of creating new one.

- first bar =[] is empty.
- for loop checks if bar is empty, add 4 to it.
- Now bar = [4] so again it checks for bar == [] but now it's value is 4. So it enters into else part and add 1.
- Now value of bar becomes 5.
- During this process it bar refers to same memory location.

---

Below example will help you to understand it better way,

```
def foo (bar = []):
    bar.append('baz')
    return bar

foo()
['baz']


foo()

['baz', 'baz']


foo()
['baz', 'baz', 'baz']
```

It keep appending default value 'baz' to the existing list each time foo() was called.
This is because, the default value for a function argument is only evaluated once, at the time of function is defined.
Thus  the bar argument is initialized to its default(i.e. an empty list) only when foo() is first defines, but then call to foo() will continue to use the same list to which bar was originally initialized.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to know about lists is that they contain references (pointers) to list objects rather than the list itself. This can be seen by running the following code:

```py
>>> list1 = [0, 1, 2, 3]
>>> list2 = list1
>>> list1[0] = 5
>>> list2
[5, 1, 2, 3]
```

Here, `list1` stores a reference to the list `[0, 1, 2, 3]`, and `list2` is given that same reference. When the list is modified through the reference in `list1`, the list referenced by `list2` is also modified.

```py
>>> def foo(bar):
        for i in range(2):
            if bar == []:
                bar.append(4)
            else:
                bar[0] += 1
            
>>> myvar = []  
>>> foo(myvar)
>>> myvar
[5]
```

Passing the list `myvar` to the function `foo()` as the argument `bar` assigns a pointer to the list `[]` to the parameter `bar`. Since `myvar` and `bar` reference the same list, when the list is modified through `bar`, retrieving the list through `myvar` reflects the same change.

Hopefully this clarifies any confusion!

Comment: "One thing to know about lists is that they contain references rather than the list itself. " that doesn't make any sense. What you are trying to say, I think, is that all variables act as references to objects. This has nothing to do with lists specifically